# JavaMail - How can I diplay content of message?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

So, I would like to actually SHOW the content of an email (Message object) obtained from JavaMail. How could I go about doing this?

Note: Im not expecting to be able to view embedded videos and such, just show the email w/pictures, preferrably in a JEditorPane, JTextPane, or JPanel?

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail comes with a simple client application that would get you started if you want to do all the work yourself.  You also might want to look at some of the open source projects in the [JavaMail Third Party Products](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html) list; some of them might have code you could reuse or at least use for guidance.